# Get numpy array that consists of ones and zeros for x combinations

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a `numpy.array` that consists of unique series of ones and zeros.
A row needs to have a length of `2*x`

When `x=2` the output is expected to look as follows:

```
[[1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]]
```

When `x=3`:

```
[[1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 1 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1]]
```

I tried `np.meshgrid` and `itertools.combinations` without any success sofar.

Please advice

Comment: `2^x` rows, and how many columns?

Comment: if x was 3 how would it appear?

Comment: If you have `2^x` rows, you can only have maximum of `x` unique columns.

Comment: @vakvakvak I made an error in my reasoning. I changed the question slightly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following:

```
from itertools import product # or simply use np.emath.nx.itertools.product
x = 2
a = np.array(list(product(*[[0,1]]*x))))
np.column_stack([a, 1 - a])

array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to generate unique integers, and extract the bits.

```
import numpy as np
n = 7
x = 4
assert (n <= (1 << (2*x))-1) # Check that n<=2**(2x)
max_number = (np.uint64(1) << np.uint64(2*x)) # 2**(2x)

# mask to extract the individual bits
bits = np.asarray([1 << x for x in range(max_number)], dtype=np.uint64)

# Generante random integers without repetition
numbers = np.random.choice(np.arange(max_number),
                           size=n, replace=False).astype(np.uint64).reshape(-1, 1)

# Convert the integers into bits
combinations = ((numbers & bits) > 0).astype(np.uint8)
```